# How to speed up ASP.NET MVC Excel file upload data validation against a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, stored-procedures

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uploads an Excel file with items that need to be validated against a stored procedure. This process works well if the Excel file has a few records, but now if I have more than over a hundred lines, it's very slow to validate.

Is there a way I can speed up his process somehow? Basically I write the data from the Excel file to a SQL Server database where I validate the data against a stored procedure. When I have about 50 records, it executes faster, as soon as I have over 100, it's very slow. Please see my code below and advise.

```
public ActionResult ValidateClaims()
{
        var domainNameOfficial = Session["domainName"];
        int sessionIdentifier = (int)Session["sessionID"];

        var claimsRecords = db.CleanSupplierClaims.Where(x => x.CleanSupplierClaimsUploadSessionID == sessionIdentifier).ToList();

        List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = claimsRecords; //(List<CleanSupplierClaim>)TempData["supplierClaimsData"];    //= new List<CleanSupplierClaim>();// = claimsRecords;// My issue is here, I get all records and not the ones the user just uploaded

        CleanSupplierClaimData supplierClaimUplaod = new CleanSupplierClaimData();

        var sqlConnection = "data source=XXXXX;initial catalog=Embrace; User ID=XXXXX; Password=XXXXXXXX;";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var claim in supplierClaimsData)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                    cmd.CommandText = "CRM.Supplier_Claim_Upload";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Invoice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = claim.Line_Number;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = claim.Total_Claim;

                    cmd.Connection = conn;

                    conn.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        claim.ST_Key = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ST_Key"));
                        claim.Error_1 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Error1"));

                        string lineNumberDoesNotExist = "Error: Invoice line number does not exist";
                        if (claim.Error_1.StartsWith(lineNumberDoesNotExist))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        claim.Warning = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Warning"));
                        claim.Error_2 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Error2"));
                        string warningCleanInclusion = "Warning";

                        if (claim.ST_Key != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(claim.Warning) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(claim.Error_1) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(claim.Error_2))
                        {
                            var existingClaimCount = db.GPClaimsReadyToImports.Count(a => a.ST_Key == claim.ST_Key && a.CleanSupplierClaimSessionID == claim.CleanSupplierClaimsUploadSessionID);
                            if (existingClaimCount == 0)

                                db.GPClaimsReadyToImports.Add(new GPClaimsReadyToImport
                                {
                                    Id = claim.Id,
                                    ST_Key = claim.ST_Key,
                                    Warning = claim.Warning,
                                    Action = claim.Action,
                                    Claim_Reference = claim.ClaimReference,
                                    Currency = claim.Currency,
                                    Error_1 = claim.Error_1,
                                    Error_2 = claim.Error_2,
                                    Line_Number = claim.Line_Number,
                                    Total_Claim = claim.Total_Claim,
                                    Domain_Username = domainNameOfficial.ToString(),//claim.Domain_Username,
                                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                    ImportFlag = true,
                                    ReadyForImport = true,
                                    CleanSupplierClaimSessionID = sessionIdentifier
                                });
                            db.SaveChanges();
                       }
                    }

                    foreach (CleanSupplierClaim saveToDBClaim in supplierClaimsData)
                    {
                        db.CleanSupplierClaims.Attach(saveToDBClaim);

                        var entry = db.Entry(saveToDBClaim);
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.Line_Number).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.Total_Claim).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.Currency).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.ClaimReference).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.Action).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.Domain_Username).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.Error_1).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.Error_2).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.Warning).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.ImportFlag).IsModified = true;
                        entry.Property(aa => aa.ReadyForImport).IsModified = true;
                        db.Entry(saveToDBClaim).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = ex.Message + ex.InnerException;
            }

            var warningCount = "Warning";
            var errorOneCont = "Error";
            var errorTwo = "ErrorTwo";

            var countWarning = supplierClaimsData.Select(x => x.Warning).Count();

            var countErrorOne = supplierClaimsData.Select(x => x.Error_1).Count();
            var countErrorTwo = supplierClaimsData.Select(x => x.Error_2).Count();

            var officialWarning = String.Concat("Warning", countWarning);

            ViewBag.WarningCount = officialWarning;
            ViewBag.ErrorOneCount = countErrorOne;
            ViewBag.ErrorTwoCount = countErrorTwo;

            Session["supplierClaimsData"] = supplierClaimsData;

            return View("ValidateClaims", supplierClaimsData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use a profiler to find where the time is mostly wasted...but if I was making this, I would rewrite this to be just one stored procedure (without using Loops inside) it will be much faster. From looking at this, I don't know why you need to grab the data from SQL and recombine from C#. SQL can handle all of that and is often smart enough to do this as fast as possible. All the Loops and LINQ(which is basically lots of loops) combined with so many looped DB calls combined leave you with exponentially degrading performance.

Comment: "Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: @montewhizdoh the reason is that my proc needs to be passed an array of items in a list, therefore I have to run the proc on each line item, is it possible to run the proc to only loop once?

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend to use EPPLUS Plugin, available of NuGet.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

I had used it for my large excel and its working perfect and speedy and OLEDB is not required at Runtime.

You can find a quick tutorial here :

http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html

Comment: I agree with you Salman, I use EPPlus too....but if you analyze Papi's code, you can see the excel was most likely already part of a table before he had a problem. As you can see, they store a sessionIdentifier with each row based on the uploaded file.

Comment: @montewhizdoh "When I have about 50 records it executes faster, as soon as I have over 100 its very slow. Please see my code below and advise", buddy i have answered for this :)

Comment: @SalmanZahid yes as I said I agree with you. EPPlus is what I use, too. I just think the OP ask the wrong question. I dont see how OP case will help anyone else but the OP.